# Verification Error with omniauth-facebook in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, omniauth-facebook

I have seen many posts about this type of error, but it doesn't seem that any that I can find apply to my case.

This is the error I am getting back from Facebook:

```
Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
```

This is the website Site URL I have set up: http://landmark.dev/

This is the redirect URI I have defined: http://landmark.dev/auth/facebook/callback

this is my omniauth.rb (cleaned)

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://landmark.dev"

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'xxx', 'xxx'
  provider :facebook, 'xxx', 'xxx', :scope => 'email'
end

OmniAuth.config.on_failure do |env|
  [200, {}, [env['omniauth.error'].inspect]]
end
```

This is my routes.rb for the callback:

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: :all
```

Twitter works great, by the way - it's just facebook that won't connect. I've been fighting with this for 3 days now and trying to find a solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:** While waiting on an answer to this to help figure it out, I tried adding in omniauth-google-oauth2 as authentication through google+ is part of the plan for this project as well. It seems I get the same error from Google:

```
"error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
```

I would think this indicates some problem on my side, but I have no idea what it could be. The other odd thing is that Twitter still works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug introduced in the last update of omniauth-oauth2 gem. Dowgrande your gem version and it should work for while.

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```

You can see discussion here

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this from your local machine (I guess you are doing so because I think that .dev domains are not available at this moment and you should be using a server like POW). The problem is that Facebook can't reach your machine.

You can use a solution like localtunnel http://localtunnel.me/ for development purposes or try to use localhost, I think localhost worked in the past although I'm not sure at this moment.

Comment: Yes, this is a local machine using POW. This seems like a really odd answer, as all Facebook needs to do is send the token back to the redirect_uri - it doesn't need to be able to reach my machine.

Comment: Or does it work differently than other OAuth2 providers? I am currently connecting this site just fine with Twitter and another local site with an IdentityServer OAuth2 server. They just send the token back to the redirect_uri however it's defined and no problem.

Comment: I think that it should be an address that Facebook can have access or localhost.

Comment: Facebook won't let me set up localhost:3000 as an App Domain - it says "top level domains are not allowed"

Comment: I tried using just localhost as an App Domain - facebook will allow that. But I get the same error described above, after adjusting all of the settings from landmark.dev to localhost

Comment: Well, I tried the localtunnel thing as well, but still get the same error posted above after updating all of the facebook app settings to the new domain. No go.

Comment: Try to write your URL here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and see what it returns.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can enter there as far as a URL is concerned. My redirect_uri doesn't have anything to display that will show up in a screen scrape of any kind. However, when I pull the home page it pulls back everything as it should.

Comment: Just to check if Facebook can really see your URL.

Comment: Answer posted above. Problem with omniauth-oauth2 - authenticating fine now